# transform.InverseTransformDirection, not getting proper output

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, direction

I have a sphere as player and I want it to move relative to camera 
and not world.

When I rotate camera along Y-axis by 90 or 270 degree and give input, it gives opposite output than expected.

Here is my script attached to sphere:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class mover : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody sphere;

    public GameObject cameraa;


    void Start () 
    {
        sphere = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }


    void Update () 
    {
        // getting input in controlVector
        Vector3 controlVector = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        // transforming direction from world space to local space[to camera]
        Vector3 localVectToCam = cameraa.transform.InverseTransformDirection (controlVector);

        //applying inputs   
        sphere.AddForce (localVectToCam * 10);
    }
}
```

when camera's direction is same as world and when camera is rotated along Y-axis by 180 degree, it works fine.

But on rotating camera along Y-axis by 90 and 270 degree is gives opposite output.

example:

camera rotation along Y-axis = 90 degree [ i.e (0,90,0) ]

input given = (0,0,1)

output got = (-1,0,0)

expected output = (1,0,0)

Can you help me to understand and correct it?

Comment: Why are you expecting `(1,0,0)`? Rotating `(0,0,1)` 90 degrees clockwise does indeed give you `(-1,0,0)`.

Comment: because when I rotate camera 90 clockwise along Y-axis, its positive Z-axis is toward worlds positive X-axis. Now if I press key 'W' , input given is (0,0,1) [relative to world], I want to move sphere in cameras +ve Z-axis which is now aligned with worlds +ve X-axis, for that I want (1,0,0).  In short I want to add force on sphere relative to camera's space rather than world space if the camera rotates.

Comment: Try removing Vector3 localVectToCam and use sphere.AddRelativeForce (controlVector * 10) instead

Comment: @Makarand Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to go the other way round actually!

[`Transform.InverseTransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html) converts a vector from world space into local space.

What you get as input however is a **local** vector on the XZ plane and [`Rigidbody.AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) expects a world space vector.

You want to apply this direction according to your player objects orientation, if e.g. pressing right (your input is `1,0,0`) the object shall move towards its `transform.right` vector.

So you rather want to convert in the opposite direction into world space to move the object in the Unity world space.

You should rather be using [`Transform.TransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection)!

```
var worldMove = transform.TransformDirection(controlVector);
sphere.AddForce(worldMove * 10);
```

Or alternatively you can also just multiply by the rotation like

```
var worldMove = transform.rotation * controlVector;
sphere.AddForce(worldMove * 10);
```

---

However, since you are using a Rigidbody there is also [`Rigidbody.AddForceRelative`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html) which basically works the same way and expects a local space vector which is then internally converted into a world space force.

```
sphere.AddRelativeForce (controlVector * 10);
```