# Unintended player movement from transform.InverseTransformDirection

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinate-transformation, inverse-transform

this is my first time posting on here. I'm working on a game using the new Unity multiplayer networking solution.
In summary, the issue is that the player is not moving as intended.

I am trying to take player input as follows:

```
Vector3 worldSpaceDir = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
```

then convert it to the object space coordinates of the player character:

```
_inputDirection = transform.InverseTransformDirection(worldSpaceDir);
```

The issue I'm having is with a rotation of 0 or 180 the player moves as expected with the WASD inputs, however, at 90 or 270 all the inputs are flipped(A = right, D = left, W = backward, S = forward).

I found a question that is exactly my question but no one responded with an answer. The question is quite old now so I wanted to ask it again for more visibility.

[Here's a link to the original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068961/transform-inversetransformdirection-not-getting-proper-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are taking the `worldSpaceDir` wrong, it should be as follow

```
Vector3 worldSpaceDir = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
```

here we take horizontal input as X and vertical input as Z, because in Unity Forward is pointed as Z and not Y.

Secondly, we do not need to use `InverseTransformDirection()` we just need `TransformDirection()` something like following

```
Vector3 inputDirection = transform.TransformDirection(worldSpaceDir);
```

here we are telling unity to convert the `worldSpaceDir` that is relative to `transform` (local direction) into a world space direction, so we might actually give a proper name to `worldSpaceDir`.

The following would work for you.

```
private void Update() {
    Move();
}

private void Move() {
    Vector3 directionToMove = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    Vector3 inputDirection = transform.TransformDirection(directionToMove);
    transform.position += inputDirection * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: I thought that because before transforming the vector the player moves in the global x and z directions that the vector was a global space vector. Which I then thought needed to be converted to local space. I didn't realize it was the other way around. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to go the other way round actually!

[`Transform.InverseTransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html) converts a vector from world space into local space.

What you get as input however is a **local** vector on the XZ plane. You want to apply this direction according to your player objects orientation, if e.g. pressing right (your input is `1,0,0`) the object shall move towards its `transform.right` vector.

So you rather want to convert in the opposite direction into world space to move the object in the Unity world space.

You should rather be using [`Transform.TransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection)!

```
var worldMove = transform.TransformDirection(input);
```

Or alternatively you can also just multiply by the rotation like

```
var worldMove = transform.rotation * input;
```

---

Note that if you are also using a Rigidbody like the question you linked there is also [`Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html) which basically works the same way and expects a local space vector which is then internally converted into a world space force.